# Check web app config settings - Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am working through a tutorial on the Microsoft Learn area for uploading image data in the cloud with Azure storage.

The tutorial instructs users to deploy a web app from a public Github sample repository, configure web app settings, and then save it to a storage account.

I have completed the steps: Hi there,

I am working through a tutorial on the Microsoft Learn area for uploading image data in the cloud with Azure storage.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/storage-upload-process-images?tabs=dotnet%2Cazure-powershell#feedback

The tutorial instructs users to deploy a web app from a public Github sample repository, configure web app settings, and then save it to a storage account.

I have completed the steps:

Deploy the sample app from the GitHub repository
Configure web app settings
I am halfway through the 'Upload an Image' section, but the image isn't showing in the Microsoft Azure Storage account I have.

Any ideas of what to check? Is there a way I can check my web app configuration settings, including viewing the linked storage account?
Thanks,

Robert

Comment: To check the Azure App Configuration Settings, Navigate to `Azure Portal` => Your `Web App` => `Configuration` => [`Application Settings`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqQ2c.png) .

Answer (score 1):

I have used the PowerShell commands and able to upload and view images without any issues.

Please check the below commands and follow the same without any change.

```cs
New-AzResourceGroup -Name -Location southeastasia

$blobStorageAccount="myblobha"

New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName myRGroup -Name $blobStorageAccount -SkuName Standard_LRS -Location southeastasia -Kind StorageV2 -AccessTier Hot


$blobStorageAccountKey = ((Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName myRGroup -Name $blobStorageAccount)| Where-Object {$_.KeyName -eq "key1"}).Value
$blobStorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $blobStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $blobStorageAccountKey

New-AzStorageContainer -Name images -Context $blobStorageContext
New-AzStorageContainer -Name thumbnails -Permission Container -Context $blobStorageContext

New-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName myRGroup -Name myAppServiceP -Tier "Free"
```

***Create Azure Web App***

```
New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName myRGroup -Name "HarshithaSampleOct" -Location "West US" -AppServicePlan "myAppServiceP"
```

***Get the sample app from the GitHub repository***

```
az webapp deployment source config --name HarshithaSampleOct --resource-group myRGroup --branch master --manual-integration --repo-url https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-upload-from-webapp
```

***Configure web app settings***

```
az webapp config appsettings set --name HarshithaSampleOct --resource-group myRGroup --settings AzureStorageConfig__AccountName=$blobStorageAccount AzureStorageConfig__ImageContainer=images AzureStorageConfig__ThumbnailContainer=thumbnails AzureStorageConfig__AccountKey=$blobStorageAccountKey
```

Now browse the URL and upload the image.

> Is there a way I can check my web app configuration settings, including viewing the linked storage account?

To check the Azure App Configuration Settings, Navigate to `Azure Portal` => Your `Web App` => `Configuration` => `Application Settings`
[image]

To view the storage Account in Azure Portal,
Go to the resource group `myRGroup` which you have created and click on the Storage Account `myblobha`

[image]

In `Storage Account` => `Containers` => `Click on Images`, you can see the uploaded images.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my App service:

[image]

I used powershell instead of the azure cli and noticed the powershell commands are incorrect. Here is a small script that I used to set the Application Settings:

```
Connect-AzAccount

$resourceGroupName  = "your_resource_group_name"
$webAppName         = "your_webapp_name"
$storageAccountName = "your_storage_account_name"

$blobStorageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName)[0].Value

$appSettings = @{ `
    "AzureStorageConfig__ImageContainer"    = "images";
    "AzureStorageConfig__AccountName"       = $storageAccountName;
    "AzureStorageConfig__ThumbnailContainer"= "thumbnails";
    "AzureStorageConfig__AccountKey"        = $blobStorageAccountKey;
    "testrun"                               = "1";
}

Set-AzWebApp -Name $webAppName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -AppSettings $appSettings
Disconnect-AzAccount
```

Fill in the variables and it should set them correct (if that is not yet the case).

Container result after uploading an image:
[image: And the result in the container]

The webapp will also provide feedback if it cannot retrieve the storage details:
[image: error wrong storage settings]

Hopefully this helps.

Kind regards

Comment: Hi @FerdiS. I have tried this and I get the following message. When I run
Set-AzWebApp -AppSettings $mysettings -Name "comandapilist" -ResourceGroupName "cloud-shell-storage-westeurope"
I receive the following:
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'AppSettings'. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Updated the answer by providing you the small script that I used. You can always manually set the AppSettings in the portal if you want.